# syntax extension for compact function definitions within a record

Tags: haskell

The following syntax is the ordinary way of defining a function scoped to a module or within a where clause.

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add x y = x + y
```

However, it does not work inside a record. At least by default, this is syntactically invalid

```
data RecordWithFunc = RecordWithFunc { func :: Int -> Int -> Int}

a :: RecordWithFunc
a = RecordWithFunc {
    func x y = x + y
}
```

Here's an example of the GHC frontend producing a parse error

```
$ runhaskell /tmp/hask.hs 

/tmp/hask.hs:5:10: error: parse error on input ‘x’
  |
5 |     func x y = x + y
  |          ^
```

Is there a syntax extension that enables arguments to appear after a field name?

Comment: If you want this to be reality then go complain to Getty that he should finish the extension: https://twitter.com/aisamanra/status/519721321681268736

Comment: Yeah. Records (and their syntax) are second-class citizens in Haskell. The `RecordWithFunc{ func = (+) }` form is sugar for using the data constructor with positional notation `RecordWithFunc (+)`. And in that there's no place to bind parameters to functions. Use a `\\` expression, per @bradrn's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no such extension. (It would be nice though!) The usual method of doing this would be to say:

```
a :: RecordWithFunc
a = RecordWithFunc {
    func = \x y -> x + y
}
```

Or even, in this case:

```
a :: RecordWithFunc
a = RecordWithFunc {
    func = (+)
}
```